# is there any block and endblock commands in css and what's the use of those?

Tags: html, css, django, templates, django-templates

I created a file named base.html in the templates folder and written the code as follows:

```
{% block page_content %}{% endblock %}
```

Now, in another file named Hello_World.html I wrote the code as

```
{% extends "base.html" %}

{% block page_content %}
<h1>Hello, World!</h1>
{% endblock %}
```

can anyone please explain the working of this code clearly as I didn't come across the commands block and endblock in css.To the one who answers Thank you very much in Advance!

Comment: This is django syntax for overwriting templates.

Answer (score 1):

This is Django.

`block` is used for overriding specific parts of a template.

You could have a block named content and this is supposed to be overridden by children that inherit from this template.

From the examples at The Django [Docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/templates/language/#template-inheritance)